# Add custom fonts with folder reference

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uifont

Is it possible to add a custom font from a referenced folder (blue one)? [image: My project structure] [image: Reference in my Info.plist] [image: PCH file]
By doing this, my fonts are not recognized in the application. Did I miss something...? Thanks a lot!

**EDIT:** @Simon Degn:
It doesn't work this way either.

I removed the path from Info.plist:
[image: My Info.plist without path reference]

And from my PCH:
[image: PCH File]

I have 6 exceptions rising without message when I launch my app:
[image: Exception]

For your information I was previously with unreferenced folder (yellow one) and it was working nicely. I'd just like to switch to the referenced folder mode from now on. If that is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if it's too late to responsed but you're nearly there.

When specifying the font in the info.plist, you're correct in specifying it as the following (where `Assets/Font/Averia_Sans_Libre` is the folder reference prefix)

```
Assets/Font/Averia_Sans_Libre/*.ttf
```

When you load the app, if you run the following you can see if the font has been loaded:

```
NSLog(@"All fonts: %@", [UIFont familyNames].description);
```

Then to use the font, use the following with the FONT NAME, not the FONT FILE NAME (which is what you've done in your example above).

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"Averia Sans Libre" size:@"15"];
```

You can find the name of the font using the example provided by Simon Degn (below)

Comment: Too late to try on my side, but I guess that make things logical.

Answer (score -1):

Yes - leave out the path. You only have to include the file name in the plist.

Run this to verify if the font is included:

```
NSArray *fontFamilies = [UIFont familyNames];

for (int i = 0; i < [fontFamilies count]; i++)
{
    NSString *fontFamily = [fontFamilies objectAtIndex:i];
    NSArray *fontNames = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:[fontFamilies objectAtIndex:i]];
    NSLog (@"%@: %@", fontFamily, fontNames);
}
```

and this will also reveal the name for the font, which will be used in the code, when you will use the font.